# Getting error while running React Native app: Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

While running React Native app I am getting the following errors.

```
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up
```

[image]

Comment: Install Android Studio and run the emulator. Make sure your Java SDK is installed.

Comment: And don't forget to check SDK location.

Comment: I have tried that but getting the same error AGAIN

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add your JRE file location like this line.

export JAVA_HOME=/home/mustafa/User/android-studio/jre/jre/

Then add the local.properties inside
React-Native-Projects/yourProjectName/android/local.properties

and add your SDK location by end of the line like:

..............

This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
...
#Mon Sep 14 20:43:05 EEST 2020

...ADD THIS LINE

***sdk.dir=/home/mustafa/Android/Sdk/***